# Where do I specify the user I want to follow in twitter hbc

Tags: twitter, twitter4j, twitter-streaming-api, twitter-hbc

Hey I would like to have the latest tweets from certain users that I will follow to be displayed on a page of my web app. So I followed the tutorial on the [git of horsebird client](https://github.com/twitter/hbc) but I don't know where I have to specify the users I want the messages from.

```
public class TwitterLatestTweets implements Runnable {
    private final static String BUNDLE_BASENAME = "configuration.twitter";
    private final static String CONSUMER_KEY = ResourceBundle.getBundle(
            BUNDLE_BASENAME).getString("consumerKey");
    private final static String CONSUMER_SECRET = ResourceBundle.getBundle(
            BUNDLE_BASENAME).getString("consumerSecret");
    private final static String TOKEN = ResourceBundle.getBundle(
            BUNDLE_BASENAME).getString("token");
    private final static String SECRET = ResourceBundle.getBundle(
            BUNDLE_BASENAME).getString("secret");
    private List<String> msgList = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        /**
         * Set up your blocking queues: Be sure to size these properly based on
         * expected TPS of your stream
         */
        BlockingQueue<String> msgQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<String>(100000);
        BlockingQueue<Event> eventQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<Event>(1000);

        /**
         * Declare the host you want to connect to, the endpoint, and
         * authentication (basic auth or oauth)
         */
        Hosts hosebirdHosts = new HttpHosts(Constants.STREAM_HOST);

        StatusesFilterEndpoint hosebirdEndpoint = new StatusesFilterEndpoint();

        Authentication hosebirdAuth = new OAuth1(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET,
                TOKEN, SECRET);

        ClientBuilder builder = new ClientBuilder().hosts(hosebirdHosts)
                .authentication(hosebirdAuth).endpoint(hosebirdEndpoint)
                .processor(new StringDelimitedProcessor(msgQueue))
                .eventMessageQueue(eventQueue);

        Client hosebirdClient = builder.build();
        hosebirdClient.connect();
        while (!hosebirdClient.isDone()) {
            try {
                String msg = msgQueue.take();
                msgList.add(msg);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            hosebirdClient.stop();

            for (String s : msgList) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is it Constants.STREAM_HOST ? Could you give me an example with the white house twitter (https://twitter.com/whitehouse) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a list of userIds to your endpoint, like this:

```
hosebirdEndpoint.followings(userIds);
```

You've got several examples [here](https://github.com/twitter/hbc/tree/master/hbc-example/src/main/java/com/twitter/hbc/example), in the same `github` project you've provided in your question. [This one](https://github.com/twitter/hbc/blob/master/hbc-example/src/main/java/com/twitter/hbc/example/FilterStreamExample.java) uses the same endpoint as in your post.

In [here](https://dev.twitter.com/streaming/reference/post/statuses/filter) you can find Twitter's documentation on the endpoint, and the full list of the parameters you can use.